# MSTest V2 with x86 and x64

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I have unit tests that require they run specifically as x86 and x64.  The problem I'm having is I can't ever run all unit tests because I have to switch the framework from the Test menu.  Is there any better way to do this in a more automated fashion? 
 Ideally there would be an Attribute I could use to specify if a test was specifically x86 or x64.  Here's an example of my code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Testx86_Success()
{
    if (!Environment.Is64BitProcess)
    {
        //Arrange
        ...

        //Act
        ...

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.Inconclusive("Can't test x64 while running in x86 process.");
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Testx64_Success()
{
    if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
    {
        //Arrange
        ...

        //Act
        ...

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.Inconclusive("Can't test x86 while running in x64 process.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare [conditional compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842590/how-do-i-set-a-conditional-compile-variable) variable and use it

```
#if comp_x64
[TestMethod]
public void Testx64_Success()
{
    if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
    {
        //Arrange
        ...

        //Act
        ...

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.Inconclusive("Can't test x86 while running in x64 process.");
    }
}
#else
   . . . . your x86 test 
#endif
```

Comment: I didn't try that but I'm assuming that would remove them from the list to be tested.  I wouldn't want to forget about them.  Thank you for providing this option but I think I like my current solution better.