How to make url parameter server agnostic in source code?
I have a desktop WPF app with .NET which has 3 versions.
MyAppDev

MyAppPreProduction

MyAppProduction

First 2 versions are used by developers to test changes.
Last one is production version which is used to distribute users.
MyAppDev connects to development server via  url=devServerUrl in constants.cs in source code for developers to test.
MyAppPreProduction connects to preproduction server via url=preprodServerUrl in constants.cs in source code for developers to test before production.
MyAppProduction connects to production server via url=prodServerUrl in constants.cs in source code.
The problem is developers sometimes forget to change this url parameter and production url stays in development app. (MyAppDev)
So developer assumes he is testing on development server but in fact he is connected to production server and changes valuable production data.
This causes problems later for us because we have to correct production data later.
What I want to ask is, is it possible to define only one url constant in source code for all 3 app's repository?
(So when developer forgets to change the url parameter, it will still connect to correct url.)


Assuming the different versions are built by different Visual Studio projects or project configurations, you may use conditional compilation, e.g. as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3842590/1136211.

Use one of the many ways that exist to configure your application. My favourite is probably MS's Configuration extensions. You can then ensure that the version of the config file on your dev machines is not the one that gets shipped out to prod. This means your devs don't have to think about what server they're connecting to anymore as they're always connecting to dev.

Can’t you use a pre-processor directive for this such as #IF DEBUG?

Maybe you could add a simple unit test that checks that.

@jeb should I test it inside code?

@BenderBoy could you please provide a simple example for my case?

@Lyrk idk, what do you mean by “versions”? Are these individual projects? Or git branches?

@BenderBoy it is in fact only one app. Just for testing purposes, developers should change url to development url. But before deploying to production, they should change url to production url.

I may not really understand what you’re trying to do or what you mean by “versions” or “agnostic”, but the simplest way to do this would be to use the RELEASE and DEBUG symbols that come predefined with Visual Studio’s default project templates. So they’re probably already there. You can add a PREPROD build configuration and put this somewhere in your code (constants.cs):
#if RELEASE
    url = "https://prod";
#elif PREPROD
    url = "https://preprod";
#else
    url = "https://dev";
#endif

Now devs can switch in the VS toolbar before compiling:
[
When publishing via Visual Studio or your build server, configure it so the Release build config is used (this is the default).
Now unless you’re shipping from \bin\Debug\, the production version will always have the production url.

It sounds like you’re just hardcoding constant strings, which is what my code above shows. You may want to load such config values from a config file instead. You could use the same code above to switch between config.json and config.debug.json, or handle that some other way.

Thank you. I added these builds as you said and these works in compiling no problem but when compile build configuration is selected as different then publish build configuration, compile build selection is published instead of publish build configuration. Do you know why?

I mean when compile configuration (in your screenshot above) is different from publish configuration (right click project/properties/build menu) it publishes from selected compile configuration. Not publish configuration. Do you know why?

I added a screenshot to main question on top. When these two are different it publishes to Release instead of Preprod. @BenderBoy

@Lyrk sorry, I’m not sure what you mean? You should be able to configure a publish profile to always use a specific build config. You seem to be using an older version of VS, so not sure what that looks like in the GUI, but in the .pubxml file it’s like <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
