# .NET framework in #if statement for compilation is not identifying net461

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I have 2 console apps. One in .Net Core 2 and one in .Net 461

I am trying to determine what framework I am running

In the case I am able to identify the the .net core but it is not able to determine it 
for my .net 461 app

Do I need to add additional information for the .net framework

Here is what I have:

```
#if NET461
   Console.WriteLine("hello from net NET461");  // expecting this to execute, but it does not
#endif
#if NETCOREAPP2_0
   Console.WriteLine("hello from net Core");
#endif
#if NETSTANDARD2_0
   Console.WriteLine("hello from net NETSTANDARD2_0");
#endif
```

**Update**

Although I didn't get the results I wanted\expected.  I was really only needed to know if it is running .net core or not.  So I just did the following

```
#if NETCOREAPP2_0
   Console.WriteLine("hello from .Net Core");
#else
   Console.WriteLine("hello from Not .Net Core");
#endif
```

Thanks for all the responses

Comment: _but it is not working for my .net 461 app_  It would help if you could provide more detail about what "not working" means.  Ideally you would provide a [mcve] and an indication of the output the example produces and an indication of the output desired.  See [ask] for more tips on asking effective questions.

Comment: What do you get as output and what value did you expect to get?

Comment: What does `Environment.Version` return? What does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed#net_d return?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  Console.WriteLine("hello from net NET461");

Comment: 4.0.30319.42000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to conditionally compile to .NET Framework version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449925/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-compile-to-net-framework-version)

Comment: @H20rider that is what you expect to run, but what is actually run, none of them or is it one of the other two options showing up?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  I was expecting to see "hello from net NET461"

Comment: @You are ***still*** not answering my question, When you run it do you get nothing at all or do you get a message other than "hello from net NET461"?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  I am not.

Comment: Conditional compilation only works if your project has multiple target frameworks.

Answer (score -1):

I have found that the structure of the csproj matters as well. This worked for me.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Please explain how this matters? Isn't that the standard generated one?

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 when I create a new project "Console App (.Net Framework)" I don't get this type of csproj format. I get something which contains this line

<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>

In this case, the #if NET461 doesn't work.